# How do I parse HTML with Perl?

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I'm new to programming and learning Perl as well.

Here is my question:  How can I parse the data below in Perl using Perl modules?

```
<h4>This is the line</h4>
abc : 130.65 TB<br>
dif : 74.52 TB<br>
asw : 56.13 TB<br>
qwe : 57<br>
```

This is the sample data from a webpage and I want an output like

```
abc = 130.65 TB
dif = 74.52 TB
asw = 56.13 TB
qwe = 57
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this is a non-constructive question; a close is not necessary.

Comment: It could be interpreted as "Recommend me an HTML parser library".

Comment: @Quentin: That certainly seems like a constructive question to me.

Answer (score 5):

Use an HTML parsing module like [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aParser) or [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder).

If you are just trying to extract the text and strip all the tags, then it should be as simple as:

```
    use HTML::TreeBuilder;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
    $tree->parse( $YOUR_HTML_TEXT );
    $tree->eof();
    my $just_the_text = $tree->as_text();
    $tree->delete;
```

You can also check http://htmlparsing.com/perl.html for more on parsing HTML with Perl.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But I have to extract only the 4 lines which i mentioned from the whole webpage.Using tree builder will fetch all the text. But how do I filter out only these 4 lines?

Comment: you don't give us enough information to tell you that. Are those lines within a div, or is there any other context information you can use?

Comment: @UshaK Your question asks how to parse those specific lines and your comment here asks how to extract those lines from a whole webpage.  For clarity, are you asking how to do both?

Comment: @UshaK: You need to have a better definition than "those lines" if we're to help you.

Comment: @mirod: they are not within a div.Actually  the source code of the webpage has the following lines

<h4>This is the line</h4>
abc : 130.65 TB<br>
dif : 74.52 TB<br>
asw : 56.13 TB<br>
qwe : 57<br>

They are just seperated with break tags.That's the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also use HTML::Tokeparser. But if you prefer work with DOM model try Mojo::DOM