# Extracting a line from a webpage using WWW::Mechanize module in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, www-mechanize

Here is my sample data from a webpage

```
<hr>
<h4>This is Second line</h4>
Some Text Here<br>
Some More Text Here<br>

<h4>This is First line</h4>
Mem Capacity : 130.65 MB<br>
Mem Used : 74.52 MB<br>
Mem Available : 56.13 MB<br>
Mem Used Percentage : 57<br>
```

I am using the following code to extract things like

```
Mem Capacity : 130.65 MB
Mem Used : 74.52 MB
Mem Available : 56.13 MB
Mem Used Percentage : 57
```

The code goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 use WWW::Mechanize;

 $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
 $url = 'some url';
 $result = $mech->get( $url );
 $content = $result->as_string();
 print $content;
 if($content =~ /Mem Capacity :([\d.]+)/)
 {
 $value = $1;
 print "Memory Capacity $value MB n";
 }
```

I am not getting any output.Can anyone tell me  where am i going wrong?

Comment: You should `use strict; use warnings;`.  I would also suggest an HTML parser instead of WWW::Mechanize in this case if all you have is HTML to deal with.

Comment: @squiguy Can you please tell how can I implement the same code with HTML parser?

Comment: This is apparently a continuation from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051191/how-do-i-parse-html-with-perl and my question is still the same: How do you define the line that you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - if($content =~ /Mem\s*Capacity\s*:\s*(\d+(.\d+)?)/i )